# How to write a klayout script to customize layer color and stipple effect?

Tags: python, scripting

I asked ChatGPT, it answered a wrong script like this:

```py
import pya

# Open the GDS file
layout = pya.Layout()
layout.read("pnl.gds")

# Specify the layer number you want to visualize
target_layer = 10

# Find all shapes on the target layer
shapes = layout.each_shape_on_layer(pya.LayerInfo(target_layer))

# Set color and stipple properties
for shape in shapes:
    shape.presentation().fill_color = pya.Color(0, 0, 0)  # Black color
    shape.presentation().fill_pattern = pya.FillPattern.FillFilledStipple

# Specify the image file path
image_path = "output_image.png"

# Export the image
layout_view = layout.view()
layout_view.save_image(image_path)
```

Please tell me how to make it right?

A way that fill the gap which `pya.FillPattern` should have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [in this thread](https://github.com/KLayout/klayout/issues/1467)

```
layout_view = pya.LayoutView()
layout_view.load_layout(gds_path)
layout_view.max_hier() 

layout_view.set_config("background-color", "#ffffff")
layout_view.set_config("grid-show-ruler", "false")
layout_view.set_config("grid-visible", "false")

for lyp in layout_view.each_layer():
    lyp.fill_color     = 0
    lyp.frame_color    = 0
    lyp.dither_pattern = 0
    
    if lyp.layer_index() in [4]:
        lyp.visible = False

layout_view.update_content()
```

Thanks to @s910324!